# Why the reputation decrement here?

Tags: discussion

I just now down-voted an answer, which is really not an answer.. Here are the screenshots that says it all.

[image]

Here it shows that I down-voted and put a comment.

Now below is the rep change notification that I got:

[image]

This is a very strange rule(?) that I loose a hard-earnt point for down-voting some that doesn't even deserve to be on the site. I am not concerned about the reputation points at all. Its more about the feeling that: You aid to clean up the trash from this beautiful site, and in turn loose a point. #Unacceptable!

Comment: Such answers should not be downvoted; they should be closed and deleted.  I'm sure there's plenty of information on the rationale for the downvoting-costs-rep-policy on [Meta.SE].

Comment: @gerrit: I did vote to close

Comment: Another option for truly bad content is to flag it for us mods.

Comment: I believe that when posts you have downvoted are deleted, you get your rep back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The philosophy is very simple.  If it's trash, it's worth spending a rep point on.  There are several good reasons for this.

- It discourages/limits malicious down voting
- Since that cost is tied to providing good content (upvotes through rep) then it means that those who provide the most good content are the most able to downvote

More at:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvote+cost

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. Its absolutely worth if we can take off some trash on this site. And, to this "It discourages/limits malicious down voting"